# MYSQL - SELECT IP v4/v6, inet_pton & bin2hex

Tags: php, mysql, select, hex, ip

I'm having bit of a trouble selecting correct values from my mysql sql server.

The ip can be ipv6 and v4.

Table: User{

...

ip binary(16)

}

```
$ip = '192.168.10.115';
$ip = bin2hex(inet_pton($ip)); // Returns c0a80a73
$result = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM User WHERE HEX(ip) = $ip");
// $result empty because in db its stored as:
// HEX(ip) = C0A80A73000000000000000000000000
```

How can I get a viable match to the  * 00000 * ?

If input was a ipv6 match this would be ok, but ip v4 not.

Comment: Try changing to `ip VARBINARY(16)` ?

Comment: If you're storing the variable as a hex number, change the column to be numeric... `HEX()` will work on a numeric input.

Comment: @drew010 I used your solution, worked perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `VARBINARY` instead of just `BINARY`?

From the MySQL Manual on [Binary/Varbinary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> If the value retrieved must be the same as the value specified for
>   storage with no padding, it might be preferable to use VARBINARY or
>   one of the BLOB data types instead.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The MySQL 5.6.3 and higher have support for IPv6 addresses - see the following: "INET6_ATON(expr)"

The data type is `VARBINARY(16)` instead of `BINARY(16)` as was suggested by earlier comments here. The only reason for this is that the MySQL functions work for both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. `BINARY(16)` is fine for storing only IPv6 addresses and saves one byte. `VARBINARY(16)` should be used when handling both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

Comment: unfortunately not for IPv6

Comment: If you want to deal with both ipv4 and ipv6 in the same field, and if you are using Mysql 5.6 or higher, you can use varbinary(16) and the functions inet6_aton and inet6_ntoa. This is a better example of why you should use MySQL functions