# Laravel varbinary(ip) using with where not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ip, varbinary

I'm using varbinary(16) to store ips in the database like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270808/5717102 .

To convert to human readable and to binary i use `inet_ntop` and `inet_pton`.
This works well, but it won't work with the where query.

```
MyModel::where('ip', $ip)->get();
```

What am I missing, shouldn't it work? I already googled, but wasn't able to find any usefull information.

Comment: Accessor and Mutator won't work while querying. Try `MyModel::where('ip', inet_pton($ip))->get();`

Comment: Didn't knew that, thanks for the hint. Works now as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessors and Mutators won't work with queries. So you should access it as `MyModel::where('ip', inet_pton($ip))->get()`

You can further just create a scope and move the logic to the model if you want to extract it out.

```
public function scopeWhereIp($query, $ip)
{
  return $query->where('ip', inet_pton($ip));
}
```

and access it as

`MyModel::whereIp($ip)->get()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MyModel::where('ip','=',$ip)->get();
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, since laravel is using the `=` operator as default if no operator is provided.